# My Sculpting Object Is Darkened And Can't Be Sculpted

Tags: sculpting

[image: This is what it looks like.]

This is what it looks like. I do not know what I did but I can't sculpted. It seems like it is not selected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the mesh is f-masked. to undo this, select the F Mask bush and select subtract. you can now make the mesh editable with this brush.

Comment: F is not a part of the brush name, it's for Fake user preventing brush to be deleted. Name of the brush is Mask. It's possible also to clear mask with Alt+M.